# Where can I find a full list of all Bitcoin mining hardware ever used?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware, history

I want to know where I can find a full list of Bitcoin mining hardware. I don't want a list of the most profitable hardware, **I just want a list with the greatest number of Bitcoin miners (don't care if it mine at low hashes p/ second or is very old)**.

The objective is to include this list in a tutorial where I explain mining to newbies and where I can show the viewers a "complete list of Bitcoin mining history".

Have some ideas about that?

Answer (score 4):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison are the canonical lists. I'm not sure that will be useful to you; there's approximately 940 products across the two lists.

If you're making a visual presentation of how mining hardware evolved, you might also find [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=7216.0) useful.